# How to pass string or parameters from batch file(cmd) to excel vba program or excel cells?

Tags: excel, vba, batch-file, cmd

I am running multiple batch files. I would like to pass message(string) when batch files starting and ending to excel vba code or excel cells.

Comment: I would handle a WMI process start and stop events from Excel VBA.

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to work in the opposite direction: Instead of launching batch files and pass the results to Excel VBA, you might use the `Shell` VBA command in order to start the mentioned batch files from VBA.